# How to search node in Jobject

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

For unspecific json, I have jobject loaded.
Now, need to search particular element across the jObject and iterate each elements.

Like,

```
{Item : { PA : P , VA : { COLL: D} } }
```

Or

```
{Fields : { CA : P , MA : { COLL: Q} } }
```

Above are the two sample JSON and want to pull , "COLL" element, it can be multiple as "element" within json node or array .
Path is not specific.

what `SelectToken` expression or easiest way to find all elements as "COLL" on any path.

Comment: Have you tried `SelectToken("COLL")`? You might also want to look at [a tutorial in JSONPath, the language used for those expressions](https://restfulapi.net/json-jsonpath/).

Comment: Thanks. this links helped... just need to do,  `SelectToken("$..COLL")`  , without $ it could not get result.

Comment: how to select element instead of value here..? so, to change value of `COLL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search for Token in JObject using `SelectToken`

```
var json = @"{'Fields' : { 'CA' : 'P' , 'MA' : { 'COLL': 'Q'} } }";
var jobject = JObject.Parse(json);
jobject.SelectToken("$..COLL");
```

For updating the token with new value, you could use the `Replace` method.

```
jobject.SelectToken("$..COLL").Replace("newValue");
```

**Output**

```
{
  "Fields": {
    "CA": "P",
    "MA": {
      "COLL": "newValue"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ok.. it just multiple so, using `selectTokens`, Is there any particular cast needed to get element/node so, it can be replace to newValue ?

Comment: I hope i understood you correctly. No, you do not need to cast it. For example, in the above case, you could use Replace(1) to update the "Q" value with 1.

Comment: anyway, it works by iterating Jtokens and then use, `replace`.